# Create virtual column containing name of table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a series of `DPISTAFF` tables from several years (i.e. `DPISTAFF2010_2011`). They each contain close to 200,000 records. I would like to be able to run a query that returns one record from each table for that individual so I can compare certain values across years. I am using a `UNION JOIN` to do this.

Currently I have the following query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _Variables (Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Value TEXT);
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO _Variables VALUES ('VarFirstName', 'John');
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO _Variables VALUES ('VarLastName', 'Smith');

SELECT LastName,FirstName,BirthYear,(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS Age,LocalExp,TotalExp,TotSalary,TotFringe,WorkLocationName,SchoolName
FROM DPISTAFF2008_2009
WHERE DPISTAFF2008_2009.FirstName = (SELECT Value FROM _Variables WHERE Name = 'VarFirstName')
    AND DPISTAFF2008_2009.LastName = (SELECT Value FROM _Variables WHERE Name = 'VarLastName')
UNION ALL

SELECT LastName,FirstName,BirthYear,(strftime('%Y', date('now')) - BirthYear) AS Age,LocalExp,TotalExp,TotSalary,TotFringe,WorkLocationName,SchoolName
FROM DPISTAFF2009_2010
WHERE DPISTAFF2009_2010.FirstName = (SELECT Value FROM _Variables WHERE Name = 'VarFirstName')
    AND DPISTAFF2009_2010.LastName = (SELECT Value FROM _Variables WHERE Name = 'VarLastName')
UNION ALL

;DROP TABLE _Variables;
```

The variable part is working fine. If I run just one SELECT statement without the second one and the UNION ALLs, then the query successfully returns 1 record, but currently I am getting `near ";": syntax error:` I don't know what my syntax error is but I think this is the right idea.

My primary issue would be differentiating between the records that are returned. What I would like to do is generate a column for viewing that would contain the name of the table that would record was returned from (at least the numbers, I only need the `2010-2011`, not the `DPISTAFF` part). But I don't want to modify the table in any way. I already have a column called `Age` that is dynamically generated without modifying the table. Is it possible to get the name of the table in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error when you try to run the full query because your `SELECT` statement is of the form:

```
select /* stuff */
union all
select /* more stuff */
union all;
```

You can't end a query with a `UNION` as you do here; the `UNION` operator appears between two queries whose result sets you wish to merge. So if you only have two tables from which to select, only one `UNION ALL` is necessary:

```
select /* stuff */
union all
select /* more stuff */;
```

If you have three tables, then you need two `UNION ALL`s:

```
select /* stuff */
union all
select /* more stuff */
union all
select /* even more stuff */;
```

And so on. As for adding the year into your result set, you can put a string literal right into your `SELECT` list and assign it an alias. So your overall query with two staff tables might look like this:

```
create temp table if not exists _Variables (Name text primary key, Value text);
insert or replace into _Variables values
    ('VarFirstName', 'John'), 
    ('VarLastName', 'Smith');

select '2008-2009' as Year, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName /* more fields */ 
    from DPISTAFF2008_2009 T1
    where T1.FirstName = (select Value from _Variables where Name = 'VarFirstName' limit 1)
        and T1.LastName = (select Value from _Variables where Name = 'VarLastName' limit 1)
union all
select '2009-2010' as Year, T2.FirstName, T2.LastName /*more fields */ 
    from DPISTAFF2009_2010 T2
    where T2.FirstName = (select Value from _Variables where Name = 'VarFirstName' limit 1)
        and T2.LastName = (select Value from _Variables where Name = 'VarLastName' limit 1);

drop table _Variables;
```

Output:

```
sqlite> .read samplequery.sql
2008-2009|John|Smith
2009-2010|John|Smith
```